# Making a video from an Image Sequence with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, command-prompt

I have a list of ordered jpg images with no pattern but the first 4 digits in the file name

**1632***385053090730920.jpg*

I tried to do as follows

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\InputImages\1632%15d.jpg" "C:\OutputVideos\video.webm"
```

but it keeps giving me

`Could find no file with path '1632%15d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4 1632%15d.jpg: No such file or directory`

How do I specify this specific file pattern?

Comment: You said bash but you're using Windows backslashes, is it WSL or something?

Comment: Windows prompt. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer